# Avoid multiple labeling in qtiles / QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, tiling

After failing to start the slippy map tiles generator .py module (where to put globalmercator.py...?), i tried this plug-in.

How can i set qgis(2.14), to not move labels, as the tile generator moves? So this way only once will be printed everthig on the features? 
Everything is zoom dependant on the map, features were created nicely, but labels are cutted, or multiplicated.

[image: too many labels..(later i modified the style order.)]